Unix makefile not executing the jar file
So I'm working on an assignment for an intro to Unix course and one of the assignments goes as follows:

Create a directory named “makeAsst” within your ~/UnixCourse directory.

Copy the files and directories for this assignment into that directory:
 - cp -r ~cs252/Assignments/cookiej/* ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/

 - Use ls and more to examine the directory structure and files 
   that you have obtained.


In that new directory, create a make file that, when make is run with no parameters, will
 - Compile the .java files (in the src/) directory, placing all 
   resulting .class files into ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin.

 - Collect all of the .class files from ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin 
   into a file ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar. This jar file 
   should be set up to run the program when invoked as (java -jar 
   cookie.jar)



Like any good make file, yours should permit the program to be rebuilt after one or more source code files have been changed, using the minimum number of rebuilding steps necessary.

Give the command:
 ~cs252/bin-s24/makeAsst



to complete the assignment.
I got all the way up to making the makefile, but I keep getting various errors.
# Define source and destination directories
SRCDIR := src
BINDIR := ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin
JARFILE := ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar

# Define Java compiler
JAVAC := javac

# Define options for Java compiler
JAVACFLAGS := -d $(BINDIR) -classpath $(SRCDIR)

# Define Java archive tool
JAR := jar

# Define options for JAR tool
JARFLAGS := cvf

# Define the list of .java files to compile
JAVA_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/cs252/*.java) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/cs252/players/*.java)

# Define the list of .class files
CLASS_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.java,$(BINDIR)/%.class,$(JAVA_FILES))

# Define the default target
.PHONY: all
all: $(JARFILE)

# Rule to compile .java files
$(BINDIR)/%.class: $(SRCDIR)/%.java
        $(JAVAC) $(JAVACFLAGS) $<

# Rule to create the JAR file
$(JARFILE): $(CLASS_FILES)
        $(JAR) $(JARFLAGS) $@ -C $(BINDIR) .

# Rule to clean the compiled files
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*.class $(JARFILE)

This is what the makefile looks like, tried to run the command java -jar cookie.jar but then I got the message "no main manifest attribute, in cookie.jar"
I then added the manifest attribute by creating the manifest.txt file with the line "Main-Class: cs252.Chomp" and I used the command jar cmf manifest.txt ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar -C ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin . to update the jar file to include the manifest option.
I then ran java -jar cookie.jar again and I was able to get the chomp game to run somewhat. After this, I tried to run the final command ~cs252/bin-s24/makeAsst to get the assignment code, but then this error message shows up and I haven't been able to get past this:
cs_jrich096@europa:~/UnixCourse/makeAsst$ ~cs252/bin-s24/makeAsst

Checking basic compilation

Checking jar file

no main manifest attribute, in cookie.jar

After running "make", the jar file cookie.jar exists, but cannot be executed\n at (eval 1) line 68.

I don't know where to go from here, so some assistance would be greatly appreciated! let me know if any further information is needed

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

(Really do read that link: If enough information to let someone reproduce the problem and test solutions isn't given as text in the body of the question itself, that question is eligible for close for lacking a [mre]. It's not reasonable to ask people to retype your makefile off of a screenshot if they want to reproduce the issue or test proposed solutions).

@CharlesDuffy thank you for the suggestion, I have made the necessary changes

You say you ran jar cmf manifest.txt ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar -C ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin ..  Did you run this by hand one time?  Or did you change your makefile to run it every time you change your code and rebuild cookie.jar?  If the former, that's probably your problem.  No doubt the makeAsst tool is cleaning your workspace and building everything from scratch, which loses your custom by-hand changes.

That's the point of writing a makefile, so you don't have to remember all the fiddly little bits of commands needed to get your program built.  Also, as above please note you should not include ANY screenshots in your question.  Not even the output: it should also be cut and pasted into a code block in your question.

You don't need the complication of the manifest file. Actually the command could be simply jar cfe ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar cs252.Chomp -C ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin .

@MadScientist I only ran it the one time, how many times should I run it and should I change the manifest code too? Please forgive me but I am a little confused. I also made the suggested edits to the post

@g00se I tried your suggestion and I got the error "Error parsing file arguments"

You certainly don't want to mixing in some arbitrary commands outside the makefile. It should do everything you need. As a sanity check please post the output of javac -version

@g00se the output is javac 17.0.10, but without the manifest file, I am not sure how to get the makefile to compile correctly and get the assignment code command to work without the line "After running "make", the jar file cookie.jar exists, but cannot be executed\n at (eval 1) line 68."

Forget my suggestion for a minute. What were your instructions about the manifest file?

@g00se there was none in the assignment description, I added the manifest file after running the java -jar cookie.jar command because I kept getting the error message "no main manifest attribute, in cookie.jar"

Then my suggestion would be apt. I know almost nothing about makefiles but I tried yours and make didn't like its syntax. I would add C and C++ tags to this question

Your makefile's recipe for building the jar needs to handle making it executable, whether by appropriate use of the jar command's e option or by appropriate use of its m option.  The latter probably would require your makefile to provide for creating a manifest file, too.  It's ok -- in fact, sometimes very useful -- to perform steps manually to test things out, but the ultimate product should not rely on any manual steps between source code as provided and desired build outputs.

Also are the files for this question available online anywhere?

@JohnBollinger I took your advice and changed my makefile to perform the function of creating its own manifest file, but now I am getting the error "Your makefile does not do enough javac compilations when src/cs252/Cookie.java is changed. at (eval 1) line 90"

@g00se unfortunately no, they are only accessible through a vpn provided by the university

@g00se I tried your answer, but I am still experiencing some problems (down below)

This worked for me. Reverse the commenting I did at the top of the file and you should be OK
# Define source and destination directories
SRCDIR := src
#BINDIR := ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin
BINDIR := /tmp/UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin
#JARFILE := ~/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar
JARFILE := /tmp/UnixCourse/makeAsst/cookie.jar

# Define Java compiler
JAVAC := javac
MAIN_CLASS := cs252.Chomp

# Define options for Java compiler
JAVACFLAGS := -d $(BINDIR) -classpath $(SRCDIR)

# Define Java archive tool
JAR := jar

# Define options for JAR tool
JARFLAGS := cvef $(MAIN_CLASS)

# Define the list of .java files to compile
JAVA_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/cs252/*.java) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/cs252/players/*.java)

# Define the list of .class files
CLASS_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.java,$(BINDIR)/%.class,$(JAVA_FILES))

# Define the default target
.PHONY: all
all: $(JARFILE)

# Rule to compile .java files
$(BINDIR)/%.class: $(SRCDIR)/%.java
    $(JAVAC) $(JAVACFLAGS) $<

# Rule to create the JAR file
$(JARFILE): $(CLASS_FILES)
    $(JAR) $(JARFLAGS) $@ -C $(BINDIR) .

# Rule to clean the compiled files
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*.class $(JARFILE)


I tried to run this and I got the error message "After running "make", the file bin/cs252/Chomp.class has not been generated. at (eval 1) line 59" I tried to revise the Makefile to ensure that all necessary Java files are recompiled when any of them change, but I am still getting the same result

I created the makefile, ran make, then after I ran ~cs252/bin-s24/makeAsst and this is the exact output ` rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
Checking basic compilation
After running "make", the file bin/cs252/Chomp.class has not been generated. at (eval 1) line 59.`

You need to check your tree instructions carefully. I have UnixCourse/makeAsst/bin/cs252/Chomp.class And btw, I ran make -f UnixCourse/makeAsst/makefile from the parent directory of UnixCourse which is also the parent of src I found that a curious tree arrangement, but it's what the instructions seem to be saying
